# Функция для создания нового файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

Пишу функцию создания нового файла в текстовом редакторе, столкнулся с проблемой.

Данный код создаёт новый файл, только если он не сохранен (если он сохранен, то при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, так как  код сразу проверяет файл на наличие не сохраненного текста).

Пробовал добавлять `else`   перед      `if answer & QMessageBox.Save: file_save()`

но в таком случае выбивает ошибку, не могу сообразить как это реализовать

```
def new_file():
        if not self.textEdit.document().isModified():
            return
        answer = QMessageBox.question(
            window, 'Новый файл',
            "У вас есть нeсохраненные изменения. Сохранить перед закрытием?",
            QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel
        )
        if answer & QMessageBox.Save:
            file_save()
        elif answer & QMessageBox.Discard:
            self.textEdit.clear()
```

Воспроизводимый пример

```
from TextEditorUI import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from TextEditorUI import Ui_MainWindow, QFont, QMainWindow, QAction  # импорт нашего сгенерированного файла
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings, QPoint, QSize
import sys

file_path = None


# TODO панель с выбором шрифтов, добавить расширение для сохраняемых и открываемых файлов
#todo  доработать новый файл

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settings = QSettings('Matewriter', 'Matewriter')

        # Функция для создания нового файла. Если файл над которым мы работаем не сохранен вызываем окно сохранения
        def new_file():
            if not self.textEdit.document().isModified():
                return
            answer = QMessageBox.question(
                window, 'Новый файл',
                "У вас есть нeсохраненные изменения. Сохранить перед закрытием?",
                QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel
            )

            if answer & QMessageBox.Save:
                file_save()
            elif answer & QMessageBox.Discard:
                self.textEdit.clear()
            

        # Функция для откртия файла
        def open_file():
            global file_path
            path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(window, "Open")[0]
            if path:
                self.textEdit.setPlainText(open(path).read())
                file_path = path

        # Функция для сохранения файла
        def file_save():
            if file_path is None:
                save_as()
            else:
                with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                    f.write(self.textEdit.toPlainText())

                self.textEdit.document().setModified(False)

        # Функция Сохранить как...
        def save_as():
            global file_path
            path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(window, "Save As")[0]
            if path:
                file_path = path
                file_save()

        # Настройки меню
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit)
        self.save_action.triggered.connect(file_save)
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(open_file)
        self.newfile_action.triggered.connect(new_file)
        self.saveas_action.triggered.connect(save_as)
        self.open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.newfile_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        # Конфиги окна
        windowScreenGeometry = self.settings.value("windowScreenGeometry")
        windowScreenState = self.settings.value("windowScreenState")

        if windowScreenGeometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(windowScreenGeometry)

        else:
            self.resize(600, 400)

        if windowScreenState:
            self.restoreState(windowScreenState)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # Записываем размер и положение окна в конфиг
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenGeometry", self.saveGeometry())
        self.settings.setValue("windowScreenState", self.saveState())
        e.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

не знаю нужно ли прикреплять ui файл от qt designer

TextEditorUI.py

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(762, 580)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.open_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_action.setObjectName(u"open_action")
        self.newfile_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.newfile_action.setObjectName(u"newfile_action")
        self.save_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.save_action.setObjectName(u"save_action")
        self.saveas_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.saveas_action.setObjectName(u"saveas_action")
        self.exit_action = QAction(MainWindow)
        self.exit_action.setObjectName(u"exit_action")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"alternate-background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 762, 22))
        self.menu = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName(u"menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.newfile_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.save_action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.saveas_action)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Matewriter", None))
        self.open_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.newfile_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439", None))
        self.save_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.saveas_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u043a\u0430\u043a...", None))
        self.exit_action.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0412\u044b\u0445\u043e\u0434", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.textEdit.setToolTip(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(tooltip)
        self.menu.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Не понял зачем вам там `else`? Ведь если `if` выполнится будет `return` и выполнение функции закончится, так что всё, что после `return` и так по факту происходит как бы в `else`.

Comment: подскажите, а куда тогда поместить `else` чтобы в случае если файл не изменен создавался новый? Хотя  я так понимаю `else` тут не отделаешься

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick добавил

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте `TextEditorUI.py`

Comment: @S.Nick добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, глобальные переменные - это зло.

Вот вам официальный пример того, что вы хотите сделать.

```
#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2014 Riverbank Computing Limited.
## Copyright (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the examples of PyQt.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
## You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
##
## "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
## met:
##   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
##   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
##     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
##     distribution.
##   * Neither the name of Nokia Corporation and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor
##     the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
##     products derived from this software without specific prior written
##     permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
## "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
## A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
## OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
## SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
## DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
## THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
## (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
## OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################


from PyQt5.QtCore import (QFile, QFileInfo, QPoint, QRect, QSettings, QSize,
        Qt, QTextStream)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QFileDialog, QMainWindow,
        QMessageBox, QTextEdit)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.curFile = ''

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()
        self.createToolBars()
        self.createStatusBar()

        self.readSettings()

        self.textEdit.document().contentsChanged.connect(self.documentWasModified)

        self.setCurrentFile('')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.writeSettings()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def newFile(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.textEdit.clear()
            self.setCurrentFile('')

    def open(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
            if fileName:
                self.loadFile(fileName)

    def save(self):
        if self.curFile:
            return self.saveFile(self.curFile)

        return self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        if fileName:
            return self.saveFile(fileName)

        return False

    def about(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "About Application",
                "The <b>Application</b> example demonstrates how to write "
                "modern GUI applications using Qt, with a menu bar, "
                "toolbars, and a status bar.")

    def documentWasModified(self):
        self.setWindowModified(self.textEdit.document().isModified())

    def createActions(self):
        root = QFileInfo(__file__).absolutePath()

        self.newAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/new.png'), "&New", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.New, statusTip="Create a new file",
                triggered=self.newFile)

        self.openAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/open.png'), "&Open...",
                self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Open,
                statusTip="Open an existing file", triggered=self.open)

        self.saveAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/save.png'), "&Save", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.Save,
                statusTip="Save the document to disk", triggered=self.save)

        self.saveAsAct = QAction("Save &As...", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.SaveAs,
                statusTip="Save the document under a new name",
                triggered=self.saveAs)

        self.exitAct = QAction("E&xit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q",
                statusTip="Exit the application", triggered=self.close)

        self.cutAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/cut.png'), "Cu&t", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.Cut,
                statusTip="Cut the current selection's contents to the clipboard",
                triggered=self.textEdit.cut)

        self.copyAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/copy.png'), "&Copy", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.Copy,
                statusTip="Copy the current selection's contents to the clipboard",
                triggered=self.textEdit.copy)

        self.pasteAct = QAction(QIcon(root + '/images/paste.png'), "&Paste",
                self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Paste,
                statusTip="Paste the clipboard's contents into the current selection",
                triggered=self.textEdit.paste)

        self.aboutAct = QAction("&About", self,
                statusTip="Show the application's About box",
                triggered=self.about)

        self.aboutQtAct = QAction("About &Qt", self,
                statusTip="Show the Qt library's About box",
                triggered=QApplication.instance().aboutQt)

        self.cutAct.setEnabled(False)
        self.copyAct.setEnabled(False)
        self.textEdit.copyAvailable.connect(self.cutAct.setEnabled)
        self.textEdit.copyAvailable.connect(self.copyAct.setEnabled)

    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.newAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.saveAsAct)
        self.fileMenu.addSeparator();
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct)

        self.editMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Edit")
        self.editMenu.addAction(self.cutAct)
        self.editMenu.addAction(self.copyAct)
        self.editMenu.addAction(self.pasteAct)

        self.menuBar().addSeparator()

        self.helpMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Help")
        self.helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAct)
        self.helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutQtAct)

    def createToolBars(self):
        self.fileToolBar = self.addToolBar("File")
        self.fileToolBar.addAction(self.newAct)
        self.fileToolBar.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileToolBar.addAction(self.saveAct)

        self.editToolBar = self.addToolBar("Edit")
        self.editToolBar.addAction(self.cutAct)
        self.editToolBar.addAction(self.copyAct)
        self.editToolBar.addAction(self.pasteAct)

    def createStatusBar(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

    def readSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("Trolltech", "Application Example")
        pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200))
        size = settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400))
        self.resize(size)
        self.move(pos)

    def writeSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("Trolltech", "Application Example")
        settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
        settings.setValue("size", self.size())

    def maybeSave(self):
        if self.textEdit.document().isModified():
            ret = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Application",
                    "The document has been modified.\nDo you want to save "
                    "your changes?",
                    QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Discard | QMessageBox.Cancel)

            if ret == QMessageBox.Save:
                return self.save()

            if ret == QMessageBox.Cancel:
                return False

        return True

    def loadFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Application",
                    "Cannot read file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return

        inf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText(inf.readAll())
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File loaded", 2000)

    def saveFile(self, fileName):
        file = QFile(fileName)
        if not file.open(QFile.WriteOnly | QFile.Text):
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Application",
                    "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (fileName, file.errorString()))
            return False

        outf = QTextStream(file)
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        outf << self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

        self.setCurrentFile(fileName);
        self.statusBar().showMessage("File saved", 2000)
        return True

    def setCurrentFile(self, fileName):
        self.curFile = fileName
        self.textEdit.document().setModified(False)
        self.setWindowModified(False)

        if self.curFile:
            shownName = self.strippedName(self.curFile)
        else:
            shownName = 'untitled.txt'

        self.setWindowTitle("%s[*] - Application" % shownName)

    def strippedName(self, fullFileName):
        return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Farodin пожалуйста